# Setup cloudwatch alert for aproaching max number of pods in cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks

How would I go about setting up cloudwatch alerts for when I am aproaching EKS pod limit.

I can calculate the number of pods active using the query:

```
SELECT SUM(node_number_of_running_pods) FROM SCHEMA(ContainerInsights, ClusterName)
```

I can calculate the max number of pods by getting the number of nodes and what size from ec2 autoscale group then refer to this https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/files/eni-max-pods.txt.

However is there a more dynamic way to get the max number from the cluster directly from maybe say `kube-proxy`?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on on MAX number?

Comment: sorry max POD number e.g from the link I posted. In my kubernetes dashboard when going to nodes - it knows the ["allocation percentage"](https://www.startpage.com/av/proxy-image?piurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.howtogeek.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fcsit%2F2021%2F08%2F4d52626b.png%3Ftrim%3D1%2C1%26bg-color%3D000%26pad%3D1%2C1&sp=1677664838T5cdd5afc8fd330ae73aae846c9e718b0f6babfdf1f0b1550e3db51fd28ea2453) I basically want to build a healthchecker in cloudwatch for when this goes over a certain percentage.